# Using handleTextChange in a custom search bar component in typescript, google autocomplete

Tags: typescript, react-native, search, autocomplete, react-props

I want the search bar to behave like a normal search bar, to retrieve information as you type.

Currently, when I type something in the search bar, it deletes whatever I type immediately after I type it. I know there is something wrong with the `handleTextChange` prop.

When I try to pass in the `handleTextChange` prop inside the `SearchBarCustom`, it is `undefined`.

I'd like it so whenever I type something, that corresponding location comes up in the search field.

Any help would be appreciated :)

```js
const SearchBarCustom = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  return <SearchBar value={value} onChangeText={setValue} {...props} />;
};

export default class SearchScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView
        style={styles.container}
        contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
        stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
      >
        <View>
          <GoogleAutoComplete
            apiKey={apiKey}
            debounce={500}
            minLength={1}
            queryTypes={'(cities)'}
          >
            {({ handleTextChange, locationResults }) => (
              <React.Fragment>
                <View style={styles.inputWrapper}>
                  <SearchBarCustom
                    onChangeText={handleTextChange} // POTENTIAL ERROR HERE
                    placeholder="Search"
                    containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#f3f2f8' }}
                    inputContainerStyle={{
                      backgroundColor: '#e3e3e9',
                      height: 30,
                    }}
                    placeholderTextColor="#96969b"
                    platform="ios"
                  />
                </View>
                <ScrollView>
                  {locationResults.map((el) => (
                    <LocationItem {...el} key={el.id} />
                  ))}
                </ScrollView>
              </React.Fragment>
            )}
          </GoogleAutoComplete>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This `onChangeText={setValue}` is the culprit. It's hard to help you if we don't know where `handleTextChange` coming from and what it should do?

Comment: If you're keen on having whatever you typed in the search bar not deleted immediately after, just remove `value={value} onChangeText={setValue}` from your `SearchBar` component

Comment: `handleTextChange` is coming from the GoogleAutoComplete component. I want it to retrieve locations as the user types in phrases. I removed `value={value} onChangeText={setValue}`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Where is `<SearchBar />` coming from? @dannym

Comment: <SearchBar /> is coming from React Native Elements. More specifically it is https://github.com/react-native-elements/react-native-elements-app/blob/daa5664127e2e2b2fba8a22e345c9d78a1401d1f/src/views/inputs.tsx#L61

Comment: Try the answer I just posted and let me know if that helps. @dannym

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `onChangeText` is an expected `prop` on `SearchBar` component, I think you should consider passing `handleTextChange` into your `SearchBarCustom` via a different name and call it after the `SearchBar` is done doing its thing.

Pass `handleTextChange` into `SearchBarCustom` as `handleTextChange` and not `onChangeText`

```js
<SearchBarCustom
  handleTextChange={handleTextChange}
  ...
/>;
```

On the `SearchBarCustom` component, instead of passing your state setter method (`setValue`) as on the `onChangeText` define a function for it and call your setter method along with the `handleTextChange` you passed.

```js
const SearchBarCustom = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  
  const onTextChangeHandler = (inputValue) => {
      setValue(inputValue);
      props.handleTextChange(inputValue)
  }

  return <SearchBar value={value} onChangeText={onTextChangeHandler} {...props} />;
};
```